# Automated way to update installer GUID in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

When updating a product to a new tag, we like to make a new installer so that the new product doesn't overwrite the old one when we're testing. (I'm aware of the issues with this, it's primarily for testing purposes.)

I believe I read that they removed the ability to change the "MSI_distID" through the wizard, which is all that is really needed (along with the update GUID which you can still generate a new one in the wizard). This can be accomplished by [creating a new installer](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/B24539086AABD599862575A100589E80) or copying the installer, deleting the old one, and renaming the copy. For some of our products, this is a little bit of a hassle (separate installers for optional applications).

Is there a way to programmatically do the same as copying and renaming the installer in the LabVIEW Project? I suppose I could [generate a new GUID using LabVIEW](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Any-GUID-generating-VI-available/m-p/1246596/highlight/true#M526000) and then do a search and replace on the LabVIEW Project, but I'm not sure if this is a good solution or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, modifying directly the project file and replacing GUID in it will work.

Comment: There really ought to be a better way, with all the scripting stuff NI is putting out. Oh well.